# How to restore SharePoint 2016 site collection in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, restore, 2016

I have taken a site collection backup from SharePoint 2016 server (16.0.4327.1000) and I'm trying to restore in SharePoint 2013 which has Septembler 2015 Cumulative Updates installed.

When I run below command the restore process is failed.

How can I restore a SharePoint 2016 site collection in SharePoint 2013 Server?

Note: if restore not possible for downgrade version can  i have any option to copy only master pages,css that developed in sharepoint 2016 Development environment

share point 2016 we are waiting for service packs for go for production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't restore it with OOTB functionality.

But if you use 3rd party tools then you can go earlier version. I used sharegate tool and moved couple of sites from higher version to lower version. You can try it as sharegate offer trial version.

Answer (score 6):

You can't restore to an earlier version of SharePoint. You can, however, take a database backup of a SharePoint 2013 Content Database, run a few PowerShell Scripts (Test-SPContentDatabase, Upgrade-SPContentDatabase and Mount-SPContentDatabase) and upgrade to SharePoint 2016.

Downgrading is impossible.

Comment: Hi i have any option to copy only masterpages,css that developed in sharepoint 2016 Development environment

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the PowerShell script to restore the site

```
Restore-SPSite  http://server_name/sites/site_name -Path C:\Backup\BackupFile.bak -Force
```

Comment: i get error in uls logs Could not deserialize site from C:\restore\site1.bak . Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Schema version of backup 16.0.79.0 does not match current schema version 15.0.4753.1000     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Restore(String filename, Boolean isADMode, Boolean& readOnlyMode, Boolean& hadWriteLock)